# I am trying to output the index and the corresponding element in my name but the index is not going up by 1 each time

Tags: python-3.x

the index is not going up by 1 as each letter is outputed.

```
aname = input('What is your name: ')
print('your name is',len(aname),'characters')
for elem in aname:
   for i in range(0,len(aname),6):
        print('Index:', i , 'Value:', elem)
```

This is my output,

```
Index: 0 Value: l
Index: 0 Value: i
Index: 0 Value: r
Index: 0 Value: a
Index: 0 Value: n
```

I need it to be

```
Index: 0 Value: l
Index: 1 Value: i
Index: 2 Value: r
Index: 3 Value: a
Index: 4 Value: n
```

how do i fix this.

Comment: Why 6 in `range(0,len(aname),6)`? What if `len(aname)` is > 6?

Answer (score 3):

Your unnecessary inner loop is incrementing by `6` (which goes out of the range immediately after the first iteration for strings with less than `7` characters), you can use `enumerate` to loop through indices and values:

```
for i, elem in enumerate(aname):
    print('Index:', i , 'Value:', elem)
```

Input:

```
liran
```

Output:

```
Index: 0 Value: l
Index: 1 Value: i
Index: 2 Value: r
Index: 3 Value: a
Index: 4 Value: n
```

Comment: oh i see now. I didnt understand the enumerate function. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

you define the start, stop and step size as range(start,stop,step size). step size defaults to 1 if not provided. In your code there is no logic to provide step = 6

you can also do it with basic for loop:

```
aname = input('What is your name: ')
print('your name is',len(aname),'characters')

for i in range(0,len(aname)):
    print('Index:', i , 'Value:', aname[i])
```

output:

```
What is your name: liran
your name is 5 characters
Index: 0 Value: l
Index: 1 Value: i
Index: 2 Value: r
Index: 3 Value: a
Index: 4 Value: n
```